# Redis Server Command Line

Tags: database, server, redis

I installed Redis server on ubuntu 20.04 with [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04) step by step. After setting password and other configuration, I run `sudo systemctl restart redis.service` but changes not be applied. Also, while Redis server was running, I got status with this command `sudo systemctl status redis` and It said me below message:
[image]

What's the problem?!

Answer (score 4):

I searched a lot and found that I should use below commands (using `systemctl` or `service`):

1. with `systemctl`:

- `sudo systemctl start redis-server.service` to start Redis server
- `sudo systemctl status redis-server.service` to get status of Redis server
- `sudo systemctl stop redis-server.service` to stop Redis server
- `sudo systemctl restart redis-server.service` to apply the changes of config file (`sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`)

2. with `service`:

- `sudo service redis-server start` to start Redis server
- `sudo service redis-server status` to get status
- active status:
  [image]
- stop status:
  [image]
- `sudo service redis-server stop` to stop Redis server
- `sudo service redis-server restart` to apply the changes of config file (`sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`)